# NSOpenPanel exception *** Assertion failure in -[NSRemoteView serviceViewSubservice]

Tags: cocoa, nsopenpanel

If I try this:

```
NSOpenPanel * openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
openPanel.canChooseDirectories    = YES;
openPanel.canChooseFiles          = YES;
openPanel.canCreateDirectories    = NO;
openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
openPanel.title = @"Select files or folders to import";

[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow: self.window
                  completionHandler: ^(NSInteger result) {
    if (result != NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
    {
        return;
    }
}];
```

It sometimes works, but sometimes I get error messages such as:

`*** Assertion failure in -[NSRemoteView serviceViewSubservice], /SourceCache/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-46.2/NSRemoteView.m:2679
2014-03-10 09:34:35.592 AppWage[52168:303] An uncaught exception was raised
2014-03-10 09:34:35.593 AppWage[52168:303] invalid
2014-03-10 09:34:35.593 AppWage[52168:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a59825c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff881fce75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a598038 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff925ebd41 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189
    4   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8736f8b0 -[NSRemoteView serviceViewSubservice] + 149
    5   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff873716d6 -[NSRemoteView viewServiceMarshalProxy:withErrorHandler:] + 43
    6   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff87366a40 -[NSRemoteView syncServiceWindow] + 32
    7   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff87367054 -[NSRemoteView didSetOriginOrSize:] + 201
    8   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff87367706 -[NSRemoteView setFrameSize:] + 231
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff9042df3e -[NSWindow _oldPlaceWindow:] + 1644
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff9042cf8c -[NSWindow _setFrameCommon:display:stashSize:] + 1633
    11  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff87373711 -[NSRemoteView serviceWindowDidResizeInProgress:] + 440
    12  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff873737d0 -[NSRemoteView serviceWindowDidResize:] + 180
    13  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff873707cf -[NSRemoteView advanceToConfigPhase] + 2458
    14  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8737177c -[NSRemoteView viewServiceMarshalProxy:withErrorHandler:] + 209
    15  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8736d9b7 -[NSRemoteView sendFontSmoothingBackgroundColorToService:] + 436
    16  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8736e725 -[NSRemoteView viewDidMoveToWindow] + 197
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff90323320 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 2899
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff90320964 -[NSView addSubview:] + 364
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff90334ac3 -[NSFrameView addSubview:] + 45
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff90342df5 -[NSWindow setContentView:] + 511
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff90ba9563 -[NSVBSavePanel init] + 287
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff9092b389 +[NSSavePanel newRemotePanel] + 309
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff9092b445 +[NSSavePanel _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel] + 120
    24  AppWage                             0x000000010006c99a -[AppDelegate onImportSalesReports:] + 714
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff9052a340 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 327
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff905452a8 -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 394
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff90544fe4 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 117
    28  AppKit                              0x00007fff9059448d -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] + 35
    29  AppKit                              0x00007fff90594309 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 104
    30  AppKit                              0x00007fff9053b0d6 NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 716
    31  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8f5b91d4 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 892
    32  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8f5b8787 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 385
    33  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8f5cc880 SendEventToEventTarget + 40
    34  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8f602640 _ZL18SendHICommandEventjPK9HICommandjjhPKvP20OpaqueEventTargetRefS5_PP14OpaqueEventRef + 420
    35  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8f635238 SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 59
    36  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8f6351e0 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 178
    37  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8f6350bf _ZL19FinishMenuSelectionP13SelectionDataP10MenuResultS2_ + 94
    38  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8f63d095 _ZL14MenuSelectCoreP8MenuData5PointdjPP13OpaqueMenuRefPt + 718
    39  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8f63ccc1 _HandleMenuSelection2 + 446
    40  AppKit                              0x00007fff904ad73c _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent + 284
    41  AppKit                              0x00007fff9030c6be _DPSNextEvent + 2170
    42  AppKit                              0x00007fff9030ba2b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
    43  AppKit                              0x00007fff902ffb2c -[NSApplication run] + 553
    44  AppKit                              0x00007fff902ea913 NSApplicationMain + 940
    45  AppWage                             0x000000010009a872 main + 34
    46  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8cfb15fd start + 1
    47  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3`

If I switch the open panel to be:

```
[openPanel beginWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSInteger result) {
    if (result != NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        return;
    }
}];
```

It works with no error, but then the open panel is no longer a sheet on my main window.

Am I not using the correct way to launch the `NSOpenPanel`?

Comment: nothing wrong in your openPanel and its implementation. You are getting this error from some other place. Put breakpoint and debug.

Comment: Thanks @AnoopVaidya, I do have an all exception breakpoint. Nothing gets caught. There is no 'other place' to get an error as this is the only code running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stopped happening after a reboot of my system. The [Mac Developers forum](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/221442?tstart=0) suggestion submitting a bug report so it has been done.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a sandboxed environment make sure that you have the correct entitlement to access files.

Setting `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write = YES` in the entitlements file solved the issue for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this could be resolved by cleaning the project and building it again. Probably something sandbox-related.

Answer (score -2):

I can obtain the same error by creating a new folder in the middle of a save operation.

If I do not create the new folder I do not get an error.

The error does not disappear as the result of rebooting, or cleaning.

```
// this saves the view as a PDF
- (BOOL) saveViewAsPDF:(NSString *)myDrawingTitle toDirectory:(NSURL *)myDirectory {

    int runResult;
    BOOL OK = NO;

    // create or get the shared instance of NSSavePanel
    NSSavePanel * sp = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    NSArray * fileTypes = @[@"pdf"];

    // set up new attributes
    [sp setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];

    [sp setNameFieldStringValue:myDrawingTitle];
    [sp setDirectoryURL:myDirectory];

    // display the NSSavePanel
    runResult = (int) [sp runModal];

// -- at this point in the cycle using the NSSavePanel to create a new folder --
// ... this error will result
//  *** Assertion failure in -[NSRemoteView updateWindowEdgeResizingRegion], /SourceCache/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-46.2/NSRemoteView.m:879

// the code then goes on and does the job (using the new folder even)

    MainController * myPtr2 = GetController();

    // if successful, save file under designated name
    if ( runResult == NSOKButton ) {    

        NSRect r = [super bounds];
        NSData * data = [self dataWithPDFInsideRect:r];
        NSURL * myURL = [sp URL];
        [data writeToURL:myURL atomically:YES];
        OK = YES;

        NSURL * myDirectory = [sp directoryURL];
        myPtr2->SetDefaultDirectoryForCurrentProcess( myDirectory );

    }

    return OK;
}
```